# sitecore- en version is unnecessarily created automatically when an image item is created under language versin en-ca

Tags: image, version, sitecore, multilingual

There exist two language versions, en and en-ca, in my sitecore, once I create an image item in media library under en-ca version, a blank en version will be created automatically, but not vice versa. Can this issue be circumvented? Btw, en is the default language version.

Comment: Do you perhaps some "$" variables such as "$name" set to a field in en layer?

Comment: When you create an item, are you creating it via a template branch or just a regular creation from the exact template? If its a branch, it could be that the branch is creating the other language

Comment: @Mark Ursino: as you know, image items are created basing on system template

Comment: @jpkeisala: sorry, can you make it a little clearer?

Comment: It is possible to add $name (or $date etc...) to a field for example Title -field in the template. This will then automatically populate Title with the name you give to the item when you create it. I was wondering that it could be that you have some field pre-populated on "en" layer.  See if some of the fields have value on "en" layer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, media items are not versionable, so that if you upload an image in one language, it will persist across all languages. You can change this in the web.config:

```
<setting name="Media.UploadAsVersionableByDefault" value="true"/>
```

Remember that if this is set to true, then language versions must then be applied to all items.